# Why does T S Eliot use "he do" in The Rum Tum Tugger?

Tags: word-usage, emphasis

In the poem [“The Rum Tum Tugger”](https://allpoetry.com/The-Rum-Tum-Tugger)  by T S Eliot, I found a use of  **do** that looks utterly *weird* to me. This is the first stanza:

> The Rum Tum Tugger is a Curious Cat:
> If you offer him pheasant he would rather have grouse.
> If you put him in a house he would much prefer a flat,
> If you put him in a flat then he'd rather have a house.
> If you set him on a mouse then he only wants a rat,
> If you set him on a rat then he'd rather chase a mouse.
> Yes the Rum Tum Tugger is a Curious Cat—
> And there isn't any call for me to shout it:
> For he will do
> As he **do** do
> And there's no doing anything about it!

The *last three lines* repeat in every stanza.

My problem is that I cannot understand the use of the **"do"** in bold.

If it were an emphatic **do** it should have been **does.**

Is the poet overlooking the grammar for it to look nicer?

Answer (score 17):

I think Eliot wanted to match it with the 'do' in the preceding line.

Or it was 'As he does* do' (which — although whimsical — is a grammatical sentence), but he changed the 'does' to 'do' to fit the style and meter of the poem.

<sup>*(I believe it's the emphatic *does* but he changed it to *do*.)</sup>

Comment: Who does using *does* change the meter of the poem? It's the same number of syllables.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: I meant: to rhyme it with 'do' in the preceding line

Comment: @Void, how does the difference between "As he do do" and "As he does do" affect the rhyme?

Answer (score 10):

It is a subjunctive, but a silly-sounding one, and very "non-natural" which is why the Elliot has used it: for the joke of having "do do".

It's not something to use in normal speech, nor even in "normal poems".

Comment: How is it a "subjunctive"? Would you please elaborate on a bit?

Comment: It's not "subjunctive". It's a form of [**Do-support**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#:~:text=The%20verb%20%22do%22%20can%20be,these%20constructions%20only%20when%20an) (or **do-insertion**) as usually used for ***emphasis*** (as in *I **do** do what I'm told*, emphatic / refutative alternative to the natural "single verb" version *I do what I'm told*).

Comment: No, I believe it is subjunctive: the auxiliary in the subjunctive, or else it will be _does_. The grounds for subjunctive are weak: I think "as he do do" is a sort of _irrealis_ (even though it is actually realis!)

Comment: It's not subjunctive, but everything else in this answer is correct: it's plainly just a silly-sounding way of saying "he will do as he does do," i.e., "he will do as he pleases (and btw did I mention he's a cat and doesn't care about your Earth grammar)."

Comment: No one is disputing that it's do-support - the question is whether the auxiliary "do", used for emphasis, has been put into the subjunctive.  However, because the grounds for subjunctive are so weak here, I think Quuxplusone may be right.

Answer (score 8):

You are perfectly correct: standard English would be "as he does do". But many dialects of English, especially a hundred years ago, used the infinitive form of auxiliary verbs such as *do* and *be*. Eliot is "dumbing down" his grammar for comic effect.

Comment: It would be better to call it the plain form.  Yeah, it is the same as the infinitive in form, but when I say "I swim", I think it would be confusing to describe "swim" as the infinitive form.  However, you may be right.  There are many dialects out there, and they were more vibrant then than now.

Comment: You be treadin' on thin ice there, I warrant, @rjpond